# the configuration file 'secrets.json' was not found and is not optional (.NET 6)

Tags: c#, .net, .net-6.0

User Secrets error is being generated in a CI/CD pipeline, when secrets.json file shouldn't be expected.

Steps:

1. Create .NET 5 project
2. Added user secrets.
3. Code runs locally and in CI/CD pipelines.
4. Upgrade to .NET 6 project (and preview NuGet 6.* packages)

Code runs locally, but fails in CI/CD pipelines, with error:

> "The configuration file 'secrets.json' was not found and is not optional."

Expected:

Code runs without the secrets.json file being present
Configuration
.NET 6, Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets: 6.0.0-preview.1.21102.12

Regression?
This works in .NET 5, Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets: 5.0.0.*

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The configuration file 'secrets.json' was not found and is not optional. The physical path is '/home/runner/work/UserSecretsRegression/UserSecretsRegression/UserSecrets/UserSecrets.Tests/bin/Release/net6.0/secrets.json'.
  Stack Trace:
      at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationProvider.HandleException(ExceptionDispatchInfo info)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationProvider.Load(Boolean reload)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileConfigurationProvider.Load()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationRoot..ctor(IList`1 providers)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilder.Build()
   at UserSecrets.Tests.UnitTest1.TestMethod1() in /home/runner/work/UserSecretsRegression/UserSecretsRegression/UserSecrets/UserSecrets.Tests/UnitTest1.cs:line 13
```

Comment: Unit tests should never depend on secrets (they are a dev machine feature only).   Can you paste the start of the unit test that configures the ConfigurationBuilder?

Comment: Thanks, yep I know, that's just an example

Comment: Your stack trace shows a path that is not a 'secrets.json' path.  User secrets are stored in `%UserProfile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\UserSecrets\<projectSecretGuid>\secrets.json`.  Is it possible that someone has added a direct reference to the secrets file, and then set that file to be 'Content'/'Copy to output' ?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/48485

Basically, it's a new feature in .NET6 that 'secrets.json' is not optional by default!

```
AddUserSecrets(this IConfigurationBuilder configuration, Assembly assembly, bool optional);
```

That 'optional' parameter should be set to 'true' in your code.

```
 var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddEnvironmentVariables()
    .AddCommandLine(args)
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
    .AddUserSecrets<Program>(true)
    .Build();
```

Comment: true that the true helped a lot and true is a game changer  saved my night

Comment: I am adding exact code but still not able to get the usersecrets from secrets.json. even after placing it in project root directory from appdata folder. The assembly Program, what it should be exactly? I'm confused about this.

Comment: only providers I'm getting are 3, environment variables, commandline, appsettings.json.

Comment: @coder9090 Do you have the environment variable DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT set to "Development"

Comment: @Neil yes. It is developement

Comment: Or: `.AddUserSecrets(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(), optional: true)`

Comment: Downvote: I added             .AddUserSecrets<Program>(optional: true)
to the code and it still gave me the same error: could not find secrets.json

Answer (score 5):

Unlike environment variables, user secrets are placed in a settings file similar to `appsettings.json`. Having similar structured off-project settings is great when you need to copy keys and values between files and there is support for adding, removing, and listing values as I will show you later in this post.

To understand user secrets, let's resume the example from the previous post. In there I had an `appsettings.json` file looking like this:

```
{
  "AppSettings": {
    "ConnectionString": "http://localhost:9000"
  },
  ...
}
```

In order to override the `AppSettings:ConnectionString` setting on individual machines, each user needs to add a user secret with the same name. The easiest approach is to right-click the project and select *Manage User Secrets*:

[image]

This creates and opens a new empty JSON file named `secrets.json`. The file is placed beneath `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\UserSecrets\<id>` where `<username>` matches your Windows user and  is a randomly generated GUID. The important thing to notice here is that the file is located outside your project directory. In order to "bind" the `secrets.json` file location to your project, Visual Studio added a bit of markup to the `csproj` file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <UserSecretsId>dda25df4-9a88-4a7e-8502-2134b74e4729</UserSecretsId>
</PropertyGroup>
```

In case you are not using Visual Studio, you can generate a random GUID and add the `<UserSecretsId>` manually.

In case you want to override the `AppSettings:ConnectionString` setting, add a similar structure to the `secrets.json` file:

```
{
  "AppSettings": {
    "ConnectionString": "http://localhost:9000?user=mehdidaustany&password=1234"
  }
}
```

You can also collapse settings like this:

```
{
  "AppSettings:ConnectionString": "http://localhost:9000?user=mehdidaustany&password=1234"
}
```

Finally add created `secrets.json` in the root of your project.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. For me, though, it was after I upgraded my VS2022 to the latest version 17.2.5 it automatically created an entry in project property (the project was already in .Net 6.0): 
 <PropertyGroup>
  <UserSecretsId>dda25df4-9a88-4a7e-8502-2134b74e4729</UserSecretsId>
</PropertyGroup>
 
 I unloaded the project, then deleted the entry and that fixed the issue. I already have all the secrets stored in a local setting file, so no need for more place to stow secrets that are not supposed to be checked in to Git repo.

Answer (score 4):

In .net 6.0, the application needs secret.json to run. in any case, if you are migrating from .net core 3.1 or .net 5.0 in order to run your application in .net 6.0:

1. run `dotnet user-secrets init` in your project folder using command-line tools.
2. make sure you have a `secret.json` file in your app domain `...\bin\Debug\net6.0`. It doesn't matter if your `secret.json` file is empty for now.

Hit F5 and run your application!

Comment: my beef about secrets.json is that the file tends to disappear completely (VS2022) and this did not happen in VS2019, I believe there is a bug in VS2022

Comment: @MC9000 This happened to me in VS2019. It had something to do with my coworkers checking in their code and me pulling it down. Same thing would happen on my coworkers end. It might be something with `<UserSecretsId>` property being overwritten in the project file.

Answer (score 0):

In latest versions, in program.cs file user secret file is not optional for dev or local environments.

```
builder.Configuration.AddUserSecrets(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(), false);
```

Make it optional by changing false to true.

```
builder.Configuration.AddUserSecrets(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(), true);
```