# VS2022 Configure Azure keyvault not seeing local secrets.json

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio, azure-keyvault, connected-services

I want to build an new .net core console application using the Azure KeyVault. I use the connected services wizard and select azure keyvault. It recognizes the vault instance I have access to but then comes a config pages like so:

[image]

Save connection string shows none as the possible options. I have a local secrets.json configured for the local secrets. Why can I not select this as an option? How do I get the wizard to recognize something here?

Comment: @KartikBhiwapurkar-MT I already knew the workaround. The question was why the wizard did not recognize it. "according to the experts it might be a bug" Is not really an solution so I am not sure if it qualifies as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

•   According to experts, there might be **bug in Visual Studio 2022** due to which the `‘secrets.json’` file is not getting saved as this doesn’t happen in **Visual Studio 2019**. As due to this bug only, you may not be able to refer the **‘local secrets.json’** file during creation of a **.Net core console application**.

You can report this bug on Visual Studio Community to Microsoft Support in here: - https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/support/. In the meantime, you can refer to the below **alternative solution** to refer to your created **‘local secrets.json’** file through an `environment variable`. To override the `AppSettings:ConnectionStrings` setting on individual machines, each user needs to add a user secret with the same name. The easiest approach is to use the **Manage user secrets** option in Visual Studio for a project.

•   This itself will create a new empty **JSON** file for the secrets and is stored in `‘C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\UserSecrets\<id>’` where  matches your `Windows user` and is a `randomly generated GUID`. Also, since this file is located outside of your project directory, you will have to bind the **‘local secrets.json’** file to your project by adding a `bit of markup to the ‘csproj’` file as below: -

```
  <PropertyGroup>
  <UserSecretsId>dda25df4-9a88-4a7e-8502-2134b74e4729</UserSecretsId>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Finally, to override the **‘AppSettings:ConnectionString’** setting, add a similar structure to the `secrets.json` file as below and place it in the root of your project.

```
   {
     "AppSettings:ConnectionString": "http://localhost:9000?user=username&password=1234"
```

}

For more details regarding this, kindly refer to the community discussion below: -

[the configuration file 'secrets.json' was not found and is not optional (.NET 6)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70056612/the-configuration-file-secrets-json-was-not-found-and-is-not-optional-net-6)